# C++ how to determine if char is first char in a word

Tags: c++

It seems like this should be simple but I can't seem to figure it out. I am trying to write a function that will return true if the character at position  pos is the first character of a word. A word it this case is defined as any string of alphanumeric characters.

Here is my latest attempt:

```
bool wordBeginsAt (const std::string& message, int pos)
{
string temp;
int x;

    for (x=pos;isAlphanumeric(message[x]==true);x++)
    {
        temp[x] = message[x];
    }
        if (temp[pos]!=0)
        {
            return false;
        }

        else

        return true;

    }

 bool isAlphanumeric (char c)
{
     return (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z')
     || (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z')
     || (c >= '0' && c <= '9');
}
```

Comment: If you're just interested in position `pos` why do you need a for loop? Also, the condition `isAlphanumeric(message[x]==true)` looks very wrong...

Comment: `return std::isalnum(message[pos]) && (pos==0 || !std::isalnum(message[pos-1]));`

Comment: this seems to be a dead end, I am trying to use string.find(" ") and the string.substr() now .... i can't believe this is function is holding back.

Comment: John3136, i was using the for loop because I need the pos of the word not the entire string ( the string is a paragraph) so I was trying to load just the "word" into a temp string then determine the pos. Gotta go for an hour or so, be back later.

Comment: [`isalpha`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/isalpha/)

Comment: isAlphanumeric(message[x]==true) gives isAlphanumeric() a boolean value (true unless it's a null byte), which is certainly not what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, `isAlphanumeric(message[x]==true)` should have been `isAlphanumeric(message[x])==true`.  But your code has other severe issues such as writing out of bounds of `temp` and the loop logic is all wrong, so I think it is best to start over.

What you need to do is:

- Check if the character is alphanumeric
- Check that either the previous character isn't, or there is no previous character

No loops or variables are required.  The second condition would occur when `pos == 0` ; you don't want to check the previous character if you are actually looking at the first character.

Comment: thanks, 
if (isAlphanumeric(message[pos])==true && isAlphanumeric(message[pos-1])==false)

did the trick.

Comment: @bryan make sure you add a special case for when `pos == 0`

Answer (score 2):

By your definition, a character is the first character in a word if it is alphanumeric *and* either it's the first character in the string or the character before it is not alphanumeric.